# Why is my attacchment serializer not saving data?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have messages and attachments to them (photos, documents, etc.). When I pass data to the serializer, I find that it is empty.

serializer:

```
class MessageAttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = MessageAttachment
        fields = ("file", "message", "size")
```

view:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def stuff_message(request):
    data = request.data.copy()
    data["sender"] = request.user.id
    serializer = MessageSerializer(data=data, context={"request": request})
    serializer.is_valid(True)
    saved_msg = serializer.save()
    if request.FILES:
        data["message"] = saved_msg
        attachment_serializer = MessageAttachmentSerializer(data=data, context={"request": request}, many=True)
        attachment_serializer.is_valid(True)
        attachment_serializer.save()
    try:
        bot.send_message(serializer.validated_data["receiver"].telegram_id, text=serializer.validated_data["text"])
    except ApiTelegramException:
        return Response("Chat undefined.", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    return Response()
```

My message serializer works fine. When trying to output validated_data or data from MessageAttachment I get an empty list. Doesn't throw errors.

Corrected to:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def stuff_message(request):
    request.data._mutable = True
    request.data["sender"] = request.user.id
    serializer = MessageSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(True)
    saved_msg = serializer.save()
    request.data["message"] = saved_msg.id
    attachments = []
    for attachment in request.FILES.getlist("file"):
        record = request.data
        record["file"] = attachment
        attachment_serializer = MessageAttachmentSerializer(data=record)
        attachment_serializer.is_valid(True)
        saved_attachment = attachment_serializer.save()
        attachments.append(saved_attachment.file)
    try:
        bot.send_message(serializer.validated_data["receiver"].telegram_id, text=serializer.validated_data["text"])
        for attachment in attachments:
            bot.send_document(serializer.validated_data["receiver"].telegram_id, attachment.file)
    except ApiTelegramException:
        return Response("Chat undefined.", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    return Response()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but make sure you are returning the `.data` attribute on your serialized data as in:
`output = MessageAttachmentSerializer(data=data).data`
Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Displays an error message. It says that you must first call the "is_valid ()" method or call the initial_data method. I called initial_data and the querydict came out.

Answer (score 0):

It was the "many" argument. It looks like cases with one file and several need to be handled differently when creating data through a serializer.

Comment: If you could include sample code here of what fixed the problem, that would help other users more in the future.